# Is there a name for this permutation?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, induction

I came across this algorithm of permuting a set: successively generate a random permutation of $N$ elements starting with $j = 1$, then $j = 2$, and so on. Once one has a random
permutation of the first $j − 1$ elements, the random
permutation of the $j$ elements, is obtained by putting n in the final
position and then interchanging
the element in position n  with the element in a randomly chosen
position which is equally likely to be either position $1$, position $2$ or
position $j$.

Is there a name for this permutation? Also, I wanted to prove that in fact this is a random permutation.

Comment: What is $n$? Did you mean $j$ perhaps? And if you have a random permutation of $j-1$ elements, there is nothing in the final ($j$-th) position, because that is the new one you haven't filled yet, so you would be displacing nothing. Please clarify what you are describing.

Comment: Yes, I meant $j$.On the last position you are adding $j$. In other words, you have a random permutation of the $j-1$ elemts, and on the $jth$ position you add element $j$.

Comment: This is the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a "random permutation" by definition, since it is picked by a process involving chance. I assume you mean "uniformly random", meaning that every possible permutation has the same probability of being picked.

There are $j!$ permutations of the values $1$ through $j$. If they are all equally likely, the probability that only one was picked is $\dfrac 1{j!}$. When $j = 1$, there is only one permutation, so no matter how the picking is done, the probability of it being picked is $1 = \dfrac 1{1!}$. Suppose it is known that for some $j-1$, your method is known to be uniform. Let's calculate the probability that a given permutation $S$ of $j$ elements is picked by your process.

First, create an permutation $S'$ as follows: if the last entry $k < j$, then exchange $k$ and $j$ in $S$. Otherwise do nothing. $S'$ is the first $j-1$ entries in the resulting permutation. By your process, $S$ cannot be picked unless $S'$ is picked first. 
Because $S'$ is a permutation of $j-1$ elements, by assumption its probability of being picked is $\dfrac 1{(j-1)!}$.

Given that $S'$ has already been picked, the next step is to uniformly choose a value from $1$ to $j$. Exactly one of these picks will lead to $S$ by your procedure. So the probability that $S$ will be picked given that $S'$ was picked is $\frac 1j$. An the complete probability that $S$ will be picked is $$P(S) = P(S')P(S|S') = \dfrac 1{(j-1)!}\dfrac 1j = \dfrac 1{j!}$$

Thus every permutation of length $j$ is equally likely to be picked. By induction this is true for all $j$. And your method is indeed uniform.